# E/FlutterFcmService( 6350): Fatal: failed to find callback Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got this error log when I build app on a Emulator.
even the app start regularly this Fatal Error appears right when main.dart is executed:
`E/FlutterFcmService( 6350): Fatal: failed to find callback`

the question is that no notifications is executed because this error appears right when I start the app without pushing any notifications.
any input?
what I use:

```
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1
```

this is the code which handle the notifications, but the error is before it will executed:

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerNotification();
    configLocalNotification();
  }



  void registerNotification() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

    firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? showNotification(message['notification'])
          : showNotification(message['aps']['alert']);
      return ;
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: $message');
      return Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
    },         onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
      return;
    },
        onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
    );



    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Consultant')
          .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
          .update({'deviceToken': token});
    }).catchError((err) {
      //Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.message.toString());
    });
  }

  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen(payload: payload,)),
    );
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'it.wytex.vibeland_pro_app'
          : 'it.wytex.vibeland_pro_app',
      'Vibeland Pro',
      'Vibeland Pro',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      icon: '@drawable/ic_stat_vibeland_pro'
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);
    print(message['body'].toString());
    print(json.encode(message));

    // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(2, message['title'].toString(),
    //     message['body'].toString(), platformChannelSpecifics,
    //     payload: json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      3, ' Hai ricevuto un messaggio  ', 'Controlla subito le Tue notifiche ', platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: '@drawable/ic_stat_vibeland_pro',
    );
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_vibeland_pro');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }
```

and background messagge are handle externally of the class:

```
Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message}");
}
```

this below the function added to Firebase

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fcm = admin.messaging();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("Notifications/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot) => {
      const name = snapshot.get("name");
      const subject = snapshot.get("subject");
      const token = snapshot.get("token");

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "" + name,
          body: "" + subject,
          sound: "default",
          icon: "@drawable/ic_stat_vibeland_pro",
        },
        data: {
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      };

      return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
    });
```

not the error I get is before we call these functions...

Comment: Please post the code that is handling your notifications, clearly something is faulty in the implementation, and the names of dependencies being used barely give any information for debugging.

Comment: Ok thanks I added.